# heroku cloudflare subdomain SSL setup

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up https on my backend app on heroku as a subdomain like this (for example):

https://api.mydomain.com

and I'm really confused by all the conflicting online docs I've found. Also, I'm rather green on all this SSL stuff.  This app will be a backend for just data serving.  My front end right now is https on OpenShift under my domain and it's working fine.  Here is what I've done:

1. I have a "hobby" dyno ($7/month) on my heroku app, which I read that I need to
   enable this stuff.
2. I have a cloudflare account which serves up my domain for the openshift front-end on https.
3. I bought my domain from GoDaddy -- so right now it simply points to the cloudflare name servers.
4. I setup the subdomain: api.mydomain.com on heroku (settings tab).  It came back and said that my "DNS Target" is api.mydomain.com.herokudns.com.  It also says "Domain: Your app can be found at http://api.mydomain.com".
5. I clicked "Configure SSL" > "Automatically configure using Automated Certificate Management" and it comes back saying to:

   "update your DNS settings to our secure domain"
6. Not really sure what that means, to be honest.  I tried to go back to cloudflare and add a DNS Record (DNS tab).  Like so:

> ```
> Type: CNAME
> Name: api                                <--is this right?
> Value: api.mydomain.com.herokudns.com    <-- what do I put here?
> ```

But this doesn't work.  How do I know?  I type 
`heroku certs:auto` and it comes back 'failing'.  Also tried value: mydomain.com.herokudns.com without the 'api' in front.  I'm really confused and the docs aren't much help.  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, in case some other poor tired programmer comes here.

Cloudflare and Heroku don't get along.  Use your SSL from cloudflare.  Here's how:

1. disable automatic certification on heroku: `heroku
   certs:auto:disable`
2. Delete your domain on heroku and start over
3. Add the (sub) domain again on heroku
4. type `heroku domains` to see what the REAL domain is now -- without ACM enabled it will probably go back to ...herokuapp.com instead of ...herokudns.com
5. Set that one up in cloudflare (DNS tab) under CNAME like so:

   CNAME | yoursubdomainname  |  yourdomainname.com.herokuapp.com
6. set up Page Rules in cloudflare to be like so:
    http://*yourdomainname.com/*  => Always use https
7. on Crypto tab use Full SSL.
8. Wait an hour or so to make sure these all take effect.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: The domain doesn't go back to herokuapp.com but reappears as herokudns.com :/

Comment: Turns out it works, but it's not yourdomainname.com.herokuapp.com but yourherokuappname.com.herokuapp.com

Comment: Sadly (NEW): "When an app is migrated to the new infrastructure, its default appname.herokuapp.com, DNS records, and any haiku.herokudns.com custom domain records are modified to point to the IP addresses of the new routing infrastructure. For a period of 24-48 hours, the app is accessible via both the new and old routing infrastructure. When the migration completes, the app will no longer be accessible via the old routing infrastructure and all traffic must flow via the new infrastructure. Requests for an app sent to the old infrastructure will result in error code: H31 Misdirected Request."

Answer (score 5):

I have found a simpler solution. The fix was mentionned in [Cloudflare's tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698-Configure-CloudFlare-and-Heroku-over-HTTPS).

The trick is to take your standard heroku app address (ex: `myapp.herokuapp.com`) INSTEAD of the `xxx.herokudns.com` displayed in heroku's SSL interface

Then, to make your custom subdomain (ex: `api.foodomain.com`) point to it, simply add a CNAME record in Cloudflare's DNS

```
CNAME api myapp.herokuapp.com
```

And it should work (it did for my case).

Comment: Sadly (NEW): "When an app is migrated to the new infrastructure, its default appname.herokuapp.com, DNS records, and any haiku.herokudns.com custom domain records are modified to point to the IP addresses of the new routing infrastructure. For a period of 24-48 hours, the app is accessible via both the new and old routing infrastructure. When the migration completes, the app will no longer be accessible via the old routing infrastructure and all traffic must flow via the new infrastructure. Requests for an app sent to the old infrastructure will result in error code: H31 Misdirected Request."